# css - shine part of document through a light box

Tags: html, css

I have a light box over a page to make sure users cannot click anywhere. Second I want to shine some elements of that page through the light box, which are editable.

Currently I use a higher z-index on these elements to get them on top of the light box. The problem is that if the page has a background color it does not come through. I specifically need to set the background color on the element that should shine through, since it is now on top of the light box. Since there can be different pages, that is not the solution.

In the example provided the popthrough element has a white background, it actually should show the blue background of the container element.

[image]

How can I set this up in CSS, so that the elements actually shine through the light box, as if there were holes in the light box?

```css
.container {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
.lightbox {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.6;
    z-index: 1;
}
.popthrough {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="lightbox"></div>
    <div class="popthrough"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the pop through to also show the background color through it, then that element should have the opacity set as wel I think. You could also use rgba color where the a is the opacity. So background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6); would be the same as background-color: white; and opacity: 0.6;

Comment: It is on top of the light box, so if the opacity is lessened, it will just show the background of the light box. You can play around with the example I provided

Comment: I think the only way to do this, is by not having the lightbox behind the popthrough. But just around it. Perhaps you can do this by using a table element. Where the popthrough is a td element without a background and the Lightbox is made by the  surrounding td's which have a transparant black background.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by setting background: inherit for the popthrough. When the container is not the parent but grand parent, or further up the chain, adding

```
.container * { background-color: inherit }
```

works as well, this can be a bit aggressive though, but works nicely to pass the actual background-color all the way through to the popthrough.

```css
.container {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
.lightbox {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.6;
    z-index: 1;
}
.popthrough {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="lightbox"></div>
    <div class="popthrough"></div>
</div>
```